# When to use `parent` and when to use `root` as first argument in a GraphQL-resolver function

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, naming-conventions, graphql-js

I've seen some tutorials and examples out there who are sometimes using `parent` and sometimes using `root` for their first argument in a graphql resolver.

What would be the correct naming in which situation and why?

For example(nodejs):

```
signup: (root, args, context, info) => signup(root, args, context, info)
```

vs

```
signup: (parent, args, context, info) => signup(parent, args, context, info)
```

or in the function which does the signup:

```
const signup(root, args, context, info) = {
    // do magic stuff
}
```

vs

```
const signup(parent, args, context, info) = {
    // do magic stuff
}
```

Comment: These are just naming conventions. These are just argument name. Your resolver is always called with 4 arguments. You can call it with even (alpha,beta,gamma,zeta) or whatever.

Comment: Yes, but is there some guide I should follow especially for root/parent? I wonder if it maybe has some valuable intention to name it this or that.

Comment: root or sometimes parent argument in each resolver call is simply the result of the previous call (initial value is null if not otherwise specified).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not an established convention here. I've seen `root`, `parent`, and `obj` all used in different reference guides. At the end of the day you can call your function arguments whatever you want -- your code will function the same.

That said, I typically use the name of the type that field being resolved in part of. So for a type like

```
type RoomRental {
  user: User
  date: Date
}
```

the resolver signature looks like this:

```
user: (roomRental, args, context, info) => {
  //
}
```

I find that this makes it easier to reason about what your resolver is doing when you (or a teammate) are reading the code. Again, this is just my preference, but you may find it helps make your code a little more digestible.

For completion, I'd also add that GraphQL.js does have a configurable `root` value. This value is passed down as the first argument in the resolvers of root-level fields (that is, fields on types like `Query` or `Mutation`). There's not much utility in passing things through the root -- anything you might pass in that way should probably go in your `context` instead. However, the `root` value is part of the implementation, and may be why you see a lot of examples use `root` as the name for that first argument.